# Windows Server 2008 R2 PowerShell and Internet Explorer 9

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer-9, windows-server-2008-r2

This is a Powershell script that runs just fine under Server 2003. We're needing to move to Server 2008 R2 and the script isn't working.  Specifically the script is not sleeping while waiting for IE to finish loading the page.

```
$objIE = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
if($objIE.ReadyState -notmatch "0|1|2|3|4")
{
    $objIE = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    if($objIE.ReadyState -notmatch "0|1|2|3|4")
    {
        Stop-Process -processname iexplore
        $objIE = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
    }
}

$objIE.Visible = $giShowResults

$objIE.Navigate($gsURL + "APAdmin.asp?cmd=login&loginname=" + $gsAdminName + "&password=" >>+ $gsAdminPassword)
while($objIE.Busy -eq $true)
{                        
    $dtNow = Get-Date
    Start-Sleep 1 # Sleep for one second
}
$objIE.Navigate($gsURL + "APAdmProcessClosings.asp?cmd=run&AutomatedProcess=y")
while($objIE.Busy -eq $true)
{
    Start-Sleep 1 # Sleep for one second
}
```

When I run with Visible set to true I can see IE open, the APAdmin.asp page loads, and then the script says it's finished without running the APAdmProcessClosings.asp page.

I've searched the Net but haven't been able to find any reason why yet.

Comment: I wonder if it is interpreting the parameter as milliseconds? Have you tried "Start-Sleep -s 1" ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the Enhanced Security Configuration was the problem.  Once I added the site to the list of trusted sites then the job would run successfully.